# Nested blocks in Django templates

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, nested

The `master` template in my Django app looks like this:

```
{% block parent %}
    Some text...
    {% block child %}
        Default content here...
    {% endblock child %}
    ...some more text
{% endblock parent %}
```

Now, this template should be overwritten in a way that the `child` block is changed:

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block child %}
    New content here...
{% endblock child%}
```

However, the rendering stays the same (printing "default content here..."). Have I missed something obvious or are nested blocks not possible? (Or, violating the DRY principle, have I to re-define the `parent` block?)

**Edit:** I'm working with Django 1.1, if that matters.

Comment: Something else is wrong here, because (also using 1.1) I am unable to replicate this problem. For me, simply overriding the child block, without any reference to the parent block, has the desired effect.

Comment: Yes, you're right. See my answer below. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, it's a bug in Django's template system. For most other cases, Ben James is right (see his comment to my question above).

In my case, the `child` block was inside a `{% ifnotequal a b %}` block, and *that* breaks the block inheritance. I consider that to be a bug, since there are dozens of natural use cases for such operations.

[The corresponding ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6510).

Comment: It's a good idea to always _test_ the code you are posting, rather than assuming that what you took out won't affect the outcome.

Comment: True, true... I had a custom template tag in it in the first place and suspected that, but after throwing it out I didn't think about the ifnotequal.

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
{% extends "master.html" %}

{% block parent %}
    {% block child %}
        New content here...
    {% endblock child%}
{% endblock parent %}
```

Comment: What if the base `parent` block contains anything other than the `child` block?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's not useful. That is partly my mistake, I updated the example for the master template above. Problem: The reason for the master template is, that there is more data in it. If I do as you suggest, all this additional data is of course lost.

Comment: doing that may break website functionality, it requests 2 times the child page, therefore it may duplicate script tags and more.